# How do I obtain CFBundleTypeIconFiles info at runtime?

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I have an app that work with pdf file. I added in the file Info.plist this:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>iconPDF</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

In my app I have a UITableViewController and in the `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, I want set the `cell.imageView.image` with the icon in `CFBundleTypeIconFiles` but I don't know how to get this icon.
I tried with `docInteractionController.icons`, but in this array I find only the default icon.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code in HockeyKit, where I did exactly this:
https://github.com/TheRealKerni/HockeyKit/blob/develop/client/iOS/BWHockeyViewController.m

Starting at Line 336:

```
NSString *iconString = nil;
    NSArray *icons = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleIconFiles"];
    if (!icons) {
        iconString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleIconFile"];
        if (!iconString) {
            iconString = @"Icon.png";
        }
    } else {
        BOOL useHighResIcon = NO;
        IF_IOS4_OR_GREATER(if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0f) useHighResIcon = YES;)

        for(NSString *icon in icons) {
            iconString = icon;
            UIImage *iconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:icon];

            if (iconImage.size.height == 57 && !useHighResIcon) {
                // found!
                break;
            }
            if (iconImage.size.height == 114 && useHighResIcon) {
                // found!
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!! But if I have more than one document type, how to distinguish between the CFBundleIconFile of a pdf document and the CFBundleIconFile of a jpg document, for example.

Comment: more document types? You only should have one Info.plist per app.